# How to display single database entry in angularjs

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I have only one text field

```
 <input type="text" name="groupname" value="">
```

I want display groupname in above textbox using angularjs

```
app.controller('get_group_name', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(site_url +    'admin/Usergroup_controller/get_available_user/1')
.then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
```

});

I am getting json data like

```
[{"groupname":"Bharat"}]
```

Only one record

How can I get this data in textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="groupname" ng-model = "names[0].groupname">
```

Ng-model is used to bind data from controller to view. I will suggest you to visit angular documentation for better understanding of Angularjs.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1452/

Comment: Yes. no issue with controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="groupname" value="" ng-model="groupname">
```

then in the promise just use the $scope variable:

```
app.controller('get_group_name', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get(site_url + 'admin/Usergroup_controller/get_available_user/1')
.then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records; 
$scope.groupname = response.data.records.groupname;
```

});

Comment: try with:$scope.groupname = response[0].groupname;

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="groupname" ng-model="name">
```

Then in controller :

```
app.controller('get_group_name', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get(site_url + 'admin/Usergroup_controller/get_available_user/1')
  .then(function (response) {
              $scope.names = response.data.records; 
              $scope.name = response.data.name;
});
```